# Handlebars - own defined custom format throwing uncaught reference error "Could not find Intl object"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, handlebars.js

I'm facing an issue when defining an own custom format using handlebars.js and handlebars-intl.js.

According to [Handlebars](https://formatjs.io/handlebars/#custom-formats) you define the formats like

```
var intlData = {
    "locales": "de-CH",
    "formats": {
        "number": {
            "CHF": {
                "style": "currency",
                "currency": "CHF"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

and then your handlebar expression

```
 {{formatNumber Amount "CHF"}}
```

The console tells me that there is a reference error: "Could not find Intl object: formats.number.CHF".

And the formatNumber function throws an error saying "A number must be provided to {{formatNumber}}.

This is how the function looks like when throwing this exception

```
 function formatNumber(num, format, options) {
        assertIsNumber(num, 'A number must be provided to {{formatNumber}}');

        if (!options) {
            options = format;
            format  = null;
        }

        var locales       = options.data.intl && options.data.intl.locales;
        var formatOptions = getFormatOptions('number', format, options);

        return $$helpers$$getNumberFormat(locales, formatOptions).format(num);
    }
```

num is filled with my sample data (100000), format with "CHF" and options contains all data provided by the model.

When I directly write the format and style into the expression it works properly and I can't really see what I'm either missing or doing wrong since I'm sure that I'm following the guidelines.

This is how you would define the format directly in the expression

```
{{formatNumber price style="currency" currency="USD"}}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Update**

This is my js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    HandlebarsIntl.registerWith(Handlebars);
    renderTemplate(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)))
});

var templateSource = $('#deals-template').html();
var handlebarsTemplate = Handlebars.compile(templateSource);

var intlData = {
    "locales": "de-CH",
    "formats": {
        "number": {
            "CHF": {
                "style": "currency",
                "currency": "CHF"
            },
            "percentage": {
                "style": "percent"
            }
        }
    }
};



function renderTemplate(data) {
    $('#template').append(handlebarsTemplate(item, { data: { intlData }}));
    });
}
```

I believe I'm passing the intlData variable correctly so this can't be the issue.

Example by handlebars example

```
var html = template(context, {
data: {intl: intlData}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally figured out what caused this exception.

As I've mentioned the handlebars example looks like this

```
var html = template(context, { data: {intl: intlData} });
```

And this is what I've passed

```
$('#template').append(handlebarsTemplate(item, { data: { intlData }}));
```

I've not defined intl..

So this is the correct way

```
$('#template').append(handlebarsTemplate(item, { data: { intl: intlData }}));
```

Maybe this answer will save someone a few hours of searching but honestly it's pretty obvious.